# Update nested object multiple fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to figure out how to update the fields nested in a child object within a document in mongodb, there doesnt seem to be a way to do it. Here's what I have.

This is an object. I want to update the fields description, amount and approved attributes

```
{
    "_id": "...",
    "transaction": {
        "amount": 1,
        "description": "Birthday Money",
        "approved": false,
        "child_id": "...",
        "user_id": "...",
        "_id": "..."
    }
}
```

I've tried pretty much everything using the $set, but most things will overwrite all fields in the transaction object except for the updated ones or set onto the main document (outside transaction).

I have an object
    data = { amount: 11, description: "new desc", approved: true }

how can I use the $set update object to update these fields and not destroying the other nested fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation):

```
db.test.update(
  {_id: '...'},
  {$set: {
    'transaction.amount' : 44,
    'transaction.approved' : true,
    'transaction.description': 'new stuff'
  }}
)
```

Do not forget `multi` if you want update many things.

Comment: Is there no other way of doing it? I may include some or all of those attributes.

Comment: @kschieck What is wrong with this way? You can include only one attribute, or as many as you need. Also you can update fields not in transaction field as well.